# Check for selector's existence before running code?

Tags: jquery

I have a document ready function to work an image carousel:

```
$(function(){
  $("#sd").carouFredSel({...
```

Trouble is, some pages do not have a carousel; that is, no "#sd" div.  Although this doesn't seem to cause a functional problem, a warning does appear in the console about it.

I was wondering how to test first if there is a div #sd on the page before trying to run the method?

Comment: Under what browser/debug settings/etc? If it's coming from the library itself, personally I wouldn't worry about it, or I'd check to see if it's configurable. If there's nothing to run the code *on*, I don't really see a significant benefit to wrapping it in the test.

Comment: yes, it's not even a warning; it looks like the plugin just has a debug statement.

Answer (score 1):

Check the existence with length

```
 var $element =  $("#sd");
 if($element.length > 0)
    $element.caroFreSel
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
if($(body).has("div#sd")){
  //code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by checking this condition: `$("#sd").length > 0`